# How to display subcategory articles in the category view?

Tags: posts, categories, permalinks

I have the wordpress category widget installed on my website that lists all categories/subcategories on my site and their hierachy:

```
Watch Accessories (1)
 - Straps (1)
Watch Glossary (5)
Watch Guides (1)
 - Maintenance (1)
Watch News (2)
 - New Releases (2)
Watch Reviews (7)
 - Christopher Ward (1)
 - Hamilton (1)
 - Seiko (2)
 - Tissot (2)
 - Vostok (1)
```

I am using the following permalink structure:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

When I click on the parent categories

> ```
> http://www.domain.com/watch-reviews/
> ```

it shows the category view and lists all articles in that category.

But when I click on a subcategory

> ```
> http://www.domain.com/watch-reviews/seiko/
> ```

it doesn't show the category view, it doesn't list all the articles in the subcategory. Instead it redirects to the first article in the sub category.

How can I get Wordpress to display all articles in a subcategory?

Comment: _»Feel free to visit domain.com to experience the issue yourself.«_ = ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of your template.
To display the subcategories in a list view as well you would have to customize the template. I do not know what kind of template you use and how the file is named which displays the subcategories, but you could change it so that it displays the articles of the current category. Therefore you will have to take a look at the wp loop.

Another option would be to look for a theme that does so.

And there are plugins to display Articles on posts, but therefore you would have to implement the category pages manually.

Comment: I am using the default WP twentyeleven theme. if this helps

Comment: Well you do not seem to be a developer and it is not like a change of one line, but changing the whole template part. So you should know Html, CSS and PHP. It would be differnt if you just wanted to add an image or change a bit of styling. Well if you are able to develop here is a good link: http://www.wphub.com/tutorials/list-posts-from-one-category/ you could coustomize that and insert it into your template. It might be that there is no fitting template part and you have to create it, here a guide to wp theming: http://chrisjdavis.org/secrets-of-wp-theming-part-1

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved the issue by disabling all plugins, then troubleshooting to find which one was causing the issue. Turned out to be yoasts seo plugin that was giving me issues.

Comment: Oh, I did not expect that... sorry... the SEO plugin should not have any impact on the display of your theme, probably it changed the urls in a way that you were redirected to the article itself - so initally the twentyeleven theme does display subcategories in a list view as well :-)